# Tish'a Veshishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*Lazy gematria for today is "סרט" - "strap"/[etc.](http://translate.google.com/#auto%7Cen%7C%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%98%0A).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 269th day counting from the start of the months' year (1 *Nisan*) is *Zos Chanuka* (if the intervening *Cheshvan* has thirty days).

Answer (score 0):

Text courtesy of the National Museum of American Jewish History

> Born and raised in Brooklyn, New York, Sandy Koufax signed on as a
>   pitcher with the Brooklyn Dodgers in 1954. In 1961, Koufax won 18
>   games and struck out **269** batters, a league record. Koufax was the
>   first major leaguer to pitch four no-hitters, including a perfect
>   game. He was named the National League's Most Valuable player in 1963
>   and became the first player to earn three Cy Young awards. At age 36
>   and 20 days, he became the youngest player ever elected to the
>   Baseball Hall of Fame. *Koufax chose not to pitch in the 1965 World
>   Series when a game fell on Yom Kippur.*